# FAQ for Physics Stack Exchange

Tags: support, faq, policy, site-faq

## Frequently Asked Questions

This thread is an index of Frequently Asked Questions, and other resources, for Physics Stack Exchange.

### General questions about Stack Exchange

For general questions about the use and customs of the Stack Exchange platform in general, see the overall FAQ,

- [**FAQ for Stack Exchange sites**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) over at [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com),
- as well as [**this site's Help Center**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help)

[This glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) may also be useful.

### Frequently Asked Questions about Physics Stack Exchange

#### Site scope

- [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)
- [My question was closed on Phys.SE. Can you recommend me another internet site where my question might be on-topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh)
- [What counts as sufficient prior research when asking a question?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)
- [Are resource recommendations allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)
- [Is non-mainstream physics appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site)
- [Are engineering questions appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site)
- [How should we handle how-to-find-a-specific-reference requests?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/how-should-we-handle-how-to-find-a-specific-reference-requests)
- [Should any check-my-work questions be made on topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic)
- [Are physics-related notation and terminology questions on-topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/are-physics-related-notation-and-terminology-questions-on-topic)

#### Moderation

- [Community, help us moderate the site!](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2920/community-help-us-moderate-the-site)
- [How do I dispute a moderator's action?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4113/how-do-i-dispute-a-moderators-action)

#### General FAQ

- [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles)
- [Can I ask several related questions in a single thread?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/can-i-ask-several-related-questions-in-a-single-thread)
- [How can I cite a question in SE?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4189/how-can-i-cite-a-question-in-se)
- [Should abbreviations and acronyms be discouraged?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6795/should-abbreviations-and-acronyms-be-discouraged)
- [How do you cite yourself?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/582/how-do-you-cite-yourself)
- [Is there a standard place to point people to learn how to typeset their equations?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/804/is-there-a-standard-place-to-point-people-to-learn-how-to-typeset-their-equation)
- [What is the policy for linking? E.g.: Why should we link to abstract pages rather than pdf files? How do we cite arXiv preprints?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11400/why-should-we-link-to-abstract-pages-rather-than-pdf-files-how-do-we-cite-arxiv)

$\ $

---

$\ $

#### How can a question be added to this FAQ?

- Ask only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question body.
  The answer goes in an answer.
- **Link back** to this index. Paste this at the end of the question:

  ```
   [Return to FAQ index](/q/11305)
  ```
- Tag as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).  When a post seems to have hit a mature state, it will have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) added by a moderator.
- After the post has the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag added to it, add a link in the above [table of contents](/q/11305).

Comment: (Apparently we didn't have one.)

Comment: That link back thing is kinda neat.

Comment: @KyleKanos I claim no credit for any of the ideas in this post, other than realizing that while MSE has such an index, we didn't thus far. The link-back thing should be added to the existing faq questions, over a suitably drawn-out period to avoid flooding the meta front page.