# Why this is opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/527341/canonical-distribution-expressed-with-entropy-or-the-number-of-states)  is closed as being opinion-based. Perhaps I do not understand English well, could someone explain in more detail what opinion-based is  on this question?

Comment: I would not have picked opinion-based, but would have voted to close (although answering question 2 is opinion based). Too broad (3 questions), homework like (1st question), just not a good fit.

Comment: Why question 2 is opinion based? It has no physical  sense therefore does not have physical interpretation.It seems to me it's  a normal question with a negative answer, why opinion- based and why closed?

Comment: Perhaps I am rong, but it seems to me that this question very well demonstrates the * typical * incorrect understanding of the fundamentals of statistical physics. therefore, it may be useful for people studying this subject.

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist Usefulness is not sufficient to cause a question here to be considered on-topic, unfortunately. All questions probably have *some* use to *someone*, so it's not a good way to evaluate questions here. Also note that your question being off topic on this specific site doesn't mean it is a poor question in general.

Comment: Well, now @rkjt50r983 will believe that he wrote not monstrous nonsense, but something "opinion-based":)

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Is this derivation correct?

[Check-my-work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) questions are generally off-topic here.

> 2) Does this form have some physical interpretation?

This is a fairly broad question. What type of physical interpretation are you looking for? Additionally this is *somewhat* opinion based, as different people will have different ideas as to what constitutes a "physical interpretation". For example, is entropy physical, or is it just a really useful tool in statistical mechanics? I am sure you would get a wide variety of opinions on this point.

> 3) Is this a useful formula for calculating some physical value?

If something is "useful" or not is subjective. And once again, "some physical value" is pretty vague.

Additionally, posts that ask multiple questions are also considered to be off-topic for this site.

Therefore, your post has many problems as it stands; it is a subjective, unclear, unfocused, check-my-work question. Since there can only be one close reason reported in the close banner (I think?), I am sure one was chosen from the list. However, this is not anything against you, and you can easily fix this. As an additional bonus, since there are no answers on the question currently, you can get away with largely editing the question and getting it reopened if you want to. Or, you can just ask a new, better question that is objective and more focused on physics concepts rather than a computation. I would suggest looking at the [FAQ](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/faq-for-physics-stack-exchange) as well as the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about what types of questions are/are not on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

A commenter writes

> I would not have picked opinion-based, but would have voted to close (although answering question 2 is opinion based). Too broad (3 questions), homework like (1st question), just not a good fit.

I was the one who closed the question, and that's exactly what I was thinking. Not a good fit, for multiple reasons. See the help center for guidance on getting the community to possibly re-open your question.